# A "trivial" assumption in measure theory that I don't get at all...

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am proving some results about measure theory, and Lebesgue measure, etc... and I am founding a certain property quite hard to deduce:

> Let $N$ be a Lebesgue measurable set such that $\lambda(N)=0$ (where $\lambda$ is the positive measure of Lebesgue). Then, there exists a countable (or I suppose, finite) collection of balls $\{B_{k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $N\subseteq \cup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} B_{k}$ and $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \lambda(B_{k})<\epsilon$, for a given $\epsilon>0$.

I am completely stucked... If someone could give me some hint on how to proceed in order to prove it or understand it... It would really help. Thanks in advanced!

**My definition of Lebesgue Measure:** Firstly, it can be proved that any open set can be expressed as the union of disjoint diadic cubes, which their closure is contained in the open set (I don't prove it, but this decomposition always exists). Due to this, I define the measure of an open set $G\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $m(G)$, as the sum of the volumes of the intervals in the previously commented decomposition. Then, on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, I define the outer Lebesgue measure, $\lambda^{*}$, which I define as following: given $A\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, $\lambda^{*}(A)=\inf\{m(G): G\textrm{ is open}, A\subseteq G\}$. Then, defining that $A$ is a Lebesgue-measurable set if, given $\epsilon >0$, $\exists G$ open set and $\exists F$ closed set such that $F\subseteq A\subseteq G$ and $m(G\setminus F)<\epsilon$, I verify that the subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ formed by the Lebesgue-measurable sets, which I call $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, is a $\sigma$- algebra. Then, the Lebesgue (positive) measure, $\lambda$, is just the restriction of $\lambda^{*}$ to $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

Comment: What is your definition of the Lebesque measure?

Comment: Use the following classic definition: $$\begin{align}&\lambda(N)=0\\\iff&\lambda^\ast(N)=0\\\iff&0=\inf\left\{\sum_{m\in\Bbb N}|R_m|:N\subseteq\bigcup_{m\in\Bbb N}R_m,\,\{R_m\}_{m\in\Bbb N}\subseteq\Bbb R^n\text{ are rectangles }\right\}\end{align}$$

Comment: @PhoemueX already added it! Sorry for the delay.

Comment: This decomposition does **not** always exist, actually. You can have that every open set in $\Bbb R^n$ has an **almost disjoint** decomposition into closed rectangles, but it is only true for $n=1$ that you can have a fully disjoint decomposition into open rectangles

Comment: That said, you should realise that your definition of $\lambda^\ast$ is most similar (and at the end of the day, equivalent) to the one I used in my previous comment. What does infimum mean? The result follows quickly

Comment: Firstly, @FShrike, thanks for your guidance. I have changed to a (I believe) correct proposition (related with decomposition of open sets in dyadic cubes under certain conditions). I am processing your previous comment, and I already got it. You are correct, is almost direct, but I was quite stucked... Thanks for your time!